# Packaging Wear 2 application

Tags: android, wear-os

I am new to application development for Android Wear. My company needs to deploy to the customer our Android Wear application without using Play Store. 
I have read this

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

but I don't understand if it is possible to use the embedded method like wear 1.x on wear 2. I tried the embedded method but when I install the phone application and if I check the log of wear I can see this message:

I/PackageChangesService: App is not installed

Before posting this thread I read on Stack Overflow many possible solution for this, like using the same name space, same permission on phone and wear etc. But I can't find a solution that works.

So on an Android Wear 2 smartwatch it is not possible to use the packaging method?

Comment: In Wear 2, the watch apps are simply standalone. How are you deploying non-Wear apps to your customer?

Comment: hi, the first installation of NON wear app is simply done manually, if there are some updates on the non wear app we use a mdm system

Comment: If by "manually" you mean sideloading via `adb`, then you can do your first installation to Wear 2 the same way. Later updates are harder; you may be able to get a client for Wear from your MDM provider, or you might look into using managed Google Play: https://developer.android.com/distribute/google-play/work.html

Answer (score 0):

From this [article](https://9to5google.com/2016/10/25/the-way-android-wear-apps-work-w-the-wear-2-0-play-store-is-going-to-be-drastically-different/),

> *A Wear 2.0 user **must** visit the Play Store on their watch to install apps. There is no auto-install like on Wear 1.X. Wear 2.0 apps
>   get full network access and can be installed completely separately
>   from the handheld app so the focus is much more on standalone Wear
>   apps than the handheld centric 1.X Wear apps*.

Comment: While this statement is true for consumers, it's not necessarily applicable to enterprise deployment, which is the context of the question.